# R: If (file.exists(

Tags: r

I am just learning R, so this might be a simple question.

I have a bunch of code that I want to run IF a certain file path that was generated earlier in the code exists. So...

1.A path is created

2.If the path exists, then the rest of the code should run

This is what this portion of the code looks like:

```
label_file=paste(label_folder,"Files/",as.matrix(babble_data)[n,3],label_extension,sep="")

if (file.exists(label_file){...
```

It is running without giving me any errors, but it is treating EVERY file path (even the ones that DO exist) like the don't exist.

Is my syntax incorrect? All the examples I can find look like this, so I have no idea why it isn't working as it is supposed to. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just save all the paths in a list and perform your operations with each element (file path) of the list?

Comment: After you create `label_file`, print it out and see if its value looks correct. You haven't shown us `label_folder` (does it have a forward slash at the end?) and `label_extension` (does it have a period at the beginning?), so it's hard to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing round bracket in the `if` statement before the curly bracket. This can have all possible side effects, although a code parsing error is the most probable one.

Additionally, `as.matrix(babble_data)[n,3]` can produce a vector of results, so `paste` can produce a vector of filenames and `if (file.exists(` would fail.